# Record multiple calculation results at each change of single input cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a spreadsheet that calculates reduced generation and emissions per fuel source for the state of Wisconsin at different levels of solar photovoltaic capacity in the state, as a percent of the total state electric generation capacity.

Right now I can put in a single value for this percent of total capacity, and the spreadsheet will calculate the results (four values) I want at that set point.

What I am looking for is a way to change that input from 1 to 100 by integers, and record a row of data for the results at each input.

I have used VBA in other (non-Microsoft) applications so I'm open to solutions with VBA, but I'm not sure how to get started with VBA in Excel.

Comment: Give it a try and provide us the code if you have any problems

Comment: @Raystafarian, I updated the question to clarify - I know a bit of VBA but not in Excel.

Comment: Try using the macro recorder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Thanks @Raystafarian for the pointer to use "record macro," that was very helpful. Here's the code I ended up using:

```
Sub iteratePV()

Dim i As Integer
Dim pasterow As Integer
Dim copyrange As String

For i = 1 To 200
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = i / 100
    Range("A2:M2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    pasterow = i + 2
    Let copyrange = "A" & pasterow
    Range(copyrange).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Next i
End Sub
```

`A2` is where I entered the input value as a percentage, with the resulting output filling the range `B2:M2`.

These results were then copied down in the subsequent rows.

Comment: Excellent, when you can, go ahead and mark your answer as correct. +1